# tricky differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help with solving this equation:

$$ y'= \frac{y}{3x-y^2} $$

is there any "trick" I don't see? I don't see any first order equation I know of here.

any hints?

edit:
the question was in the first order linear equation section. can it be arranged to this form?
$$ y'= p(x)y = q(x) $$

Comment: Your question will be better if you also provide the context where this differential equation appeared. And even better if you showed us what you have tried, and/or tell us about the tools you are using, or is supposed to be using.

Comment: thank you, I added more info.

Comment: yeah I agree with you. the problem is it does not look like anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y}{3x-y^2} $$

It can be rearranged as $$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{3x-y^2}{y} $$

Which means $$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{3x}{y} - y $$

It is a linear equation. You can solve it accordingly.

Comment: I did not think of that. great! thank you

Answer (score 2):

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y}{3x-y^2} $$
HINT :
$$ \frac{dx}{dy}=3\frac{x}{y}-y $$
Considering the function $x(y)$, this is a first order linear ODE easy to solve.

To convince you, let $x=Y$ and $y=X$ :
$$Y'=\frac{dY}{dX}=3\frac{Y}{X}-X $$
I suppose that you can continue.

NOTE :

In the first edition of the question, the equation was : $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{y}{3x^2-y^2}$ which is also solvable, but more complicated. With the same trick: considering the inverse function $x(y)$, the ODE becomes a Riccati ODE. The classical method to solve this kind of ODE leads to the solution involving Bessel functions. This is an implicit form of solution because, in this case, the inverse function $y(x)$ cannot be expressed on a closed form.

Answer (score 0):

this equation can be exact the integration factor is:

$$ \mu(x)= \frac{1}{y^4} $$

so after multiplying you get:

$$ \frac{3x-y^2}{y^4}dy - \frac{1}{y^3}dx $$

from here it can be solved like an ordinary exact equation.